# Node package manager keeps on loading in installing package depenencies

Tags: json, node.js, express, pug, package.json

I am studying node js and I created a package.json like this:

```
{
    "name": "NodeExpress",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "description": "My Simple Express",
    "main": "app.js",
    "author": {
        "name": "My Name",
        "email": "name@email.com"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "*",
        "jade": "*",
    }
}
```

When I checked my node_modules it has all the dependencies I need but in my console it's just loading. What does it mean? Is it still downloading? 
When I checked the time it is almost 20 minutes past away since I install the dependencies.

Is it fine if I stop the execution of node packager installer?

Comment: What exactly is loading in console? If you app runs fine then it has all the required modules. Side note: Specify semvers of dependencies instead of `*`

Comment: the (/) forward slash symbol.